# Convert PPT to HTML and word doc to HTML using PHP code

Tags: php, openoffice-writer

In my new (PHP) project my requirement is to convert ppt and doc to html using php.
Does anybody know how it can be done?

I search so many forums and found that we can convert ppt to html using EXEC() command from php code by calling OPENOFFICE software.

Can anybody tell me what is the command of openoffice to convert ppt to html.

Can anybody help me how it will done  on windows  and linux server. My local machine have windows and server is in linux.

Also if somebody help to convert doc to html?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows there will not be many problems but on linux You will have some headaches to get it working

use something like:

```
$sCmd = "$sLibreOfficeBin --headless --invisible --nologo --nofirststartwizard --convert-to html --outdir $sTmpFolder "old_file.ppt";
```

Comment: what is $sLibreOfficeBin? Is it path of openooffice installed into c: drive ?

Comment: @HemantAgrawal - LibreOffice is a forked version of OpenOffice. They're separate projects but basically the same. So the answer to your question is "yes, it's the location of the OOo executable program file".

Comment: I have to install LibreOffice  ? we can't do it using openoffice directly ? in my local pc i already installed openoffice.

Comment: i have tried with openoffice command directly , but it's not working.

Comment: sorry but "not wokring" doesn't help me much to help You... instead of html try HTML. You should get error if You doing something wrong...